# Ajax Basic of Data Processing

Tags: php, ajax

I am learning ajax with php. And know how to do GET/POST and pass or receive data using :

1. query string
2. JSON
3. XML

Is there any other way I can send data / get response without the above 3 choices? I want to send a full object with lot of form data. Looking for all possible options.

Any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The understanding the format sent by the browser should be understood by the server.

You can use javascript to encode the object and form data and receive it on the server side and parse it.

**GET** method is for requesting data ( search queries for example ) . The url usually has a limit for length.

**POST** method is for sending data that is to be saved) . Uploading images or videos (which are binary data) or data provided by user ( like plain text)

Answer (score 0):

Just check this out , a lot of features included

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/